# Building a responsive div with a dynamic background image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am building a site using a static page builder called Hugo (written in GO) which dynamically fetches a background image. I am using bootstrap v3 as the base theme.

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{ .path-to-dynamic-file }}');">
```

I need to load smaller versions of the image for mobile. I will create an additional field in the cms to pull in the mobile image. However I cannot reference the file through css as the path will change when a new image is chosen. I would rather not build duplicate divs as there is text content inside.

Is my only option a java script based image swap or is there a quirky technique I have missed. This must be a very common requirement so I would be interested to hear people's approaches to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use media attribute in css declaration. See this link:

[HTML  media Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dyna-bg-img"></div>
<style>
.dyna-bg-img{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url('{{ .path-to-dynamic-file-for-desktop }}') no-repeat center center;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.dyna-bg-img{
background-image: url('{{ .path-to-dynamic-file-for-mobile }}');
}
}
</style>
```

first of all, do not render your image inline with any tag. create "style" tag and call your image in your layout. this code will reduce the usage of "!important". and this will work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In my case using the style tag within the html file solved my requirement:

```
<style>
      .hero-long {
        background-image: url('{{ .Params.media_item_2.api_object.fields.file.url }}');
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .hero-long {
          background-image: url('{{ .Params.media_item.api_object.fields.file.url }}');
        }
      } 

 </style>
```